# Why are my regular clicks being picked up as LongPresses?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

This code worked up until I converted my project from ios4 to ios6 (+ARC) and swapped my xib files for storyboards. Now any click I make is counted as a long press.

***Gesture setup***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

for(UIButton *button in buttons)
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1;
    longPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [button addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
}
```

}

***LongPress Method***

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        NSLog(@"duplicate press cancelled");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"LongPress Received");
}
```

***Storyboard***
[image]

Comment: If you remove the `longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1;` part, is there any difference? Also try changing it to `1.0f` instead of '1'.

Comment: @ACB Neither work. Is it possible the issue could be with how the IBActions are linked? This worked fine prior to using storyboards.

Comment: Where are those buttons actions set?

Comment: @ACB Within the longPressDetected method and linked within the storyboard: http://gyazo.com/c16309b30289adcf5f67293e8ebf2600.png?1362077168

Comment: Looks like you have linked your buttons to this action in storyboard. Remove it in storyboard and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot you have added, you have linked the buttons to `longPressDetected:` in storyboard. You need to remove it in storyboard and it will work fine.

Basically it was executing the button action which was also pointing to the same method.

Answer (score 1):

replace your code to this and then check:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
[button addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
```